# Font styling H!

Tags: seo, fonts

I will be changing the font style/sizes on my website. The header tags will be properly itemized H1, H2, H3, etc.

I am wondering if we change the font styles to the image on the left. The current is on the left and the proposed change is on the right.
[image]

Comment: To me, the fonts look the same on the right and the left.  The one that says 30px looks to be the same height as the one that says 66px.  Are you really changing the font style or are you changing H1 tags to H2 tags or something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.